# No response from JSR223 Sampler

Tags: encryption, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have code like this in JSR223 Sampler , and it gets passed also. But not able to see any output as response. Not sure what i have missed in it.

```
import android.util.Base64;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;

String Original_String= ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
String Trim1=Original_String.substring(0, Original_String.lastIndexOf(","));
String Trim2=Trim1.replaceFirst("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String Trim3=Trim2.replaceFirst("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String[] parts = Trim3.split(":");
String myString = parts[1].substring(1, parts[1].length()-1);
String final_string=myString.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
log.info(final_string);
String input="4000221111111111";

try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(final_string.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key k=kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
        //return (PublicKey) k;
        def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPadding","BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
      log.info( Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP));
}
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could any one help me out on this Please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to have response data you need to go for one of the following approaches:

```
return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

or even better:

```
SampleResult.setResponseData(Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP), 'UTF-8')
```

See [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class JavaDoc for all available functions, this way you have full control of response code, headers, body, message, etc.

You may also be interested in [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article which contains comprehensive information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Tried @Dmitri T. But no use :(

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere in your code, if you create JSR223 Sampler with `return 'foo'` code you will see `foo` as response data

Comment: if i run the same code on eclipse , i am getting result. I think jmeter is missing something :(